# howto add hive properties at runtime in spark-shell

Tags: apache-spark, hive

How do you set a hive property like: `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` at runtime? Or at least a more dynamic way of setting a property like the above, than putting it in a file like  `spark_home/conf/hive-site.xml`

Comment: You can use `set <property.you.want.to.set>;` inside your `.hql` query.

Comment: I've tried this, however this does not seem to have effect. Also setting sqlContext.setConf("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir", "/path") does not work

Comment: I can see that spark-sql actually has a `--hiveconf` parameter. This is not available in spark-shell

Comment: @hbogert were you able to resolve this problem? I'm encountering someting similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37061544/hive-configuration-for-spark-integration-tests

Comment: hi @hbogert did you have the chance to try my suggestion below? I was curious if that worked for you

Comment: hi @AlexandrosBiratsis I'm afraid I am no longer able to verify that. this question is 3 and half years old :) I do vaguely remember that the exact 'hive.metastore.warehouse.dir' was problematic, but others worked fine when trying to set them at runtime.  So to err on the safe side, I think I cannot accept your answer at this point. Can you verify if you can actually change `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` ?

Comment: hi @hbogert I am sorry I didn't provide earlier details about my attempts. But yes it worked as described below. I updated my post with the latest details. Please keep in mind that I am using Spark 2.4.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I faced the same issue and for me it worked by setting Hive properties from Spark (2.4.0). Please find below all the options through spark-shell, spark-submit and SparkConf.

**Option 1 (spark-shell)**

```
spark-shell --conf spark.hadoop.hive.metastore.warehouse.dir=some_path\metastore_db_2
```

Initially I tried with spark-shell with `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` set to `some_path\metastore_db_2`. Then I get the next warning:

> Warning: Ignoring non-spark config property:
>   hive.metastore.warehouse.dir=C:\winutils\hadoop-2.7.1\bin\metastore_db_2

Although when I create a Hive table with:

```
bigDf.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("big_table")
```

The Hive metadata are stored correctly under metastore_db_2 folder.

When I use `spark.hadoop.hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` the warning disappears and the results are still saved in the metastore_db_2 directory.

**Option 2 (spark-submit)**

In order to use `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` when submitting a job with spark-submit I followed the next steps.

First I wrote some code to save some random data with Hive:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("metastore_test").setMaster("local")
val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._
var dfA = spark.createDataset(Seq(
      (1, "val1", "p1"),
      (2, "val1", "p2"),
      (3, "val2", "p3"),
      (3, "val3", "p4"))).toDF("id", "value", "p")

dfA.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("metastore_test")

spark.sql("select * from metastore_test").show(false)
```

Next I submitted the job with:

```
spark-submit --class org.tests.Main \
        --conf spark.hadoop.hive.metastore.warehouse.dir=C:\winutils\hadoop-2.7.1\bin\metastore_db_2 
        spark-scala-test_2.11-0.1.jar
```

The metastore_test table was properly created under the `C:\winutils\hadoop-2.7.1\bin\metastore_db_2` folder.

**Option 3 (SparkConf)**

Via SparkSession in the Spark code.

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("metastore_test")
      .set("spark.hadoop.hive.metastore.warehouse.dir", "C:\\winutils\\hadoop-2.7.1\\bin\\metastore_db_2")
      .setMaster("local")
```

This attempt was successful as well.

The question which still remains is why I have to extend the property with `spark.hadoop` in order to work as expected?

Comment: answer to your last question: 
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.3.1/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/SparkHadoopUtil.scala#L501