# custom spark does not find hive databases when running on yarn

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn, hdp

Starting a custom version of spark on yarn in HDP works fine following the tutorial from https://georgheiler.com/2019/05/01/headless-spark-on-yarn/ i.e. following:

```
# download a current headless version of spark
export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$(hadoop classpath)
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/conf
export SPARK_HOME=<<path/to>>/spark-2.4.3-bin-without-hadoop/
<<path/to>>/spark-2.4.3-bin-without-hadoop/bin/spark-shell --master yarn --deploy-mode client --queue <<my_queue>> --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions='-Dhdp.version=2.6.<<version>>' --conf spark.yarn.am.extraJavaOptions='-Dhdp.version=2.6.<<version>>'

Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.4.3
      /_/
```

However, a:

```
spark.sql("show databases").show
```

only returns:

```
+------------+
|databaseName|
+------------+
|     default|
+------------+
```

Now trying to pass the original HDP configuration (which is apparently not read in by my custom version of spark) like:

one:

```
--files /usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/conf/hive-site.xml
```

two:

```
--conf spark.hive.metastore.uris='thrift://master001.my.corp.com:9083,thrift://master002.my.corp.com:9083,thrift://master003.my.corp.com:9083' --conf spark.hive.metastore.sasl.enabled='true' --conf hive.metastore.uris='thrift://master001.my.corp.com:9083,thrift://master002.my.corp.com:9083,thrift://master003.my.corp.com:9083' --conf hive.metastore.sasl.enabled='true'
```

three:

```
--conf spark.yarn.dist.files='/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/conf/hive-site.xml'
```

four:

```
--conf spark.sql.warehouse.dir='/apps/hive/warehouse'
```

all does not help to solve the issue.
How can I get spark to recognize the hive databases?

Comment: Probably related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32586793/howto-add-hive-properties-at-runtime-in-spark-shell/53581393#53581393) one

Comment: Finally answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63668341/spark-3-x-on-hdp-3-1-in-headless-mode-with-hive-hive-tables-not-found with the pre-built jars including Hive

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the `hive-site.xml` located in the **/usr/hdp/hdp.version/hive/conf** or **/opt/hdp/hdp.version/hive/conf**, depending upon where the HDP is installed, in to the `conf` directory of the headless spark installation. Now when you restart the Spark-Shell it should pick this hive configuration and load all the schemas present in Apache Hive

Comment: `/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/conf/hive-site.xml`was already copied and did also not work.
Now following your suggestion and using:
`/usr/hdp/current/hive-client/conf/hive-site.xml`, it fails as mentioned above.

Comment: You need to copy the `hive-site.xml` file in side the **hive/conf** folder which is located under the folder named **2.6.5.xxx** inside `/usr/hdp/`. For my installation, the path is as follows: `/usr/hdp/2.6.5.0-292/hive/conf/`

Comment: `/usr/hdp/current/hive-client` is a softlink to the `/usr/hdp/<<my_version>>/hive/conf/`, but as mentioned above somehow the wrong configuration is loaded. My destination for the copy is: `<<path/to>>/spark-2.4.3-bin-without-hadoop/conf`

Comment: Do you have **spark-thrift-sparkconf.conf** in your `<<path/to>>/spark-2.4.3-bin-without-hadoop/conf` directory? This file is generated by Apache Ambari for Apache Spark2 bundled with your HDP distribution.

Comment: No, but this is also not in the original: `ls /usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/conf` path

Comment: The File I mentioned in my last comment resides in `/usr/hdp/2.6.5.0-xxx/spark2/conf` directory. The File is generated by Ambari when we are installing the HDP distribution. You should be looking at `/usr/hdp/2.6.5.0-xxx/spark2/conf` instead of `/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/conf`.

Comment: Even copying `spark-defaults.conf  spark-env.sh` did not fix the issue, and even in `/usr/hdp/2.6.5.0-xxx/spark2/conf` there is no such file for me. However, I can find this file on a different cluster node. **But even with this file** it still fails to find the databases.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193684/discussion-between-yayati-sule-and-georg-heiler).

Answer (score 0):

Hive jars need to be in the classpath of Spark for hive support to be enabled.
if the hive jars are not present in classpath, the catalog implementation
 used is `in-memory`
In spark-shell we can confirm this by executing

```
sc.getConf.get("spark.sql.catalogImplementation")
```

which will give `in-memory`

### Why are hive classes required

```
    def enableHiveSupport(): Builder = synchronized {
      if (hiveClassesArePresent) {
        config(CATALOG_IMPLEMENTATION.key, "hive")
      } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
          "Unable to instantiate SparkSession with Hive support because " +
            "Hive classes are not found.")
      }
    }
```

[SparkSession.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.scala#L1107)

```
  private[spark] def hiveClassesArePresent: Boolean = {
    try {
      Utils.classForName(HIVE_SESSION_STATE_BUILDER_CLASS_NAME)
      Utils.classForName("org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf")
      true
    } catch {
      case _: ClassNotFoundException | _: NoClassDefFoundError => false
    }
  }
```

If the classes are not present, Hive support is not enabled.
Link to the [code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/repl/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/repl/Main.scala#L102) where the above checks happen as part of Spark shell initialization.

In the above code pasted as part of question, `SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH` is populated only with the Hadoop classpath and **the paths to Hive jars missing**.

Comment: But isn't spark by default compiled with hive support?

Comment: Spark is compiled against Hive but Hive jars are not a path of the classpath at runtime. User can either make it part of classpath or set `spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars` or use the spark code compiled with profile `-Phive`(https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html#building-with-hive-and-jdbc-support), so that hive jars are available in the spark assembly directory.

Comment: If we are using the distribution as mentioned in the blog(https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/hadoop-provided.html), it does not have Hive or Hadoop jars and has to be supplied at runtime.

Comment: That sounds really promising. I will test it in a minute. Meanwhile: do you add the full of `/usr/hdp/current/hive-client/lib`? Or only parts of it?

Comment: We need to add the full path of the lib folder, I am not sure which directory has the Hive jars in HDP distribution though

Comment: But I am still having the same problem:
`export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH="/usr/hdp/current/hive-client/lib*:${SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH}"`

Comment: Doesn't solve it and`echo $SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH
/usr/hdp/current/hive-client/lib*:/usr/hdp/<<hdpVers>>/hadoop/conf:/usr/hdp/<<hdpVers>>/hadoop/lib/*:/usr/hdp/<<hdpVers>>/hadoop/.//*:/usr/hdp/<<hdpVers>>/hadoop-hdfs/./:/usr/hdp/<<hdpVers>>/hadoop-hdfs/lib/*:/usr/hdp/<<hdpVers>>/hadoop-hdfs/.//*:/usr/hdp/<<hdpVers>>/hadoop-yarn/lib/*:/usr/hdp/<<hdpVers>>/hadoop-yarn/.//*:/usr/hdp/<<hdpVers>>/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/*:/usr/hdp/<<hdpVers>>/hadoop-mapreduce/.//*:/usr/hdp/<<hdpVers>>/tez/*:/usr/hdp/<<hdpVers>>/tez/lib/*:/usr/hdp/<<hdpVers>>/tez/conf` is loaded

Comment: The hive classpath seems wrong, can we add a forward slash after lib followed by * and give a try. And also can we check the value of sc.getConf.get("spark.sql.catalogImplementation") after shell starts.

Comment: Correct. Fixing the path now leads to loading the jars, but now I am in the classpath hell. `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: jline.console.completer.CandidateListCompletionHandler.setPrintSpaceAfterFullCompletion(Z)V
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.jline.JLineConsoleReader.initCompletion(JLineReader.scala:139)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.jline.InteractiveReader.postInit(JLineReader.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1$$anonfun$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:190)`

Comment: trying: `export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$(hadoop classpath)
cp -R /usr/hdp/current/hive-client/lib/*hive* .
export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH="/path/to/hivestuff/*:${SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH}"` again does not return the databases from hive.

Comment: but maybe I am missing some jars. I will your link later

Comment: Ok, also tried to manually put the 2.14.6 jline jar into sparks lib folder and setting the hive classpath - it does not help. Only an in -memory hive metastore is loaded.

Comment: Quick way to check if our work around works is to start spark-sql instead of spark-shell(has a issue since > 2.40 version), after adding only the Hive jars to classpath and listing tables.

Comment: intersting: `/path/to/spark-2.4.3-bin-without-hadoop/bin/spark-sql --conf spark.drver.extraJavaOptions='-Dhdp.version=2.6.<<HDPV>>' --conf spark.yarn.am.extraJavaOptions='-Dhdp.version=2.6.<<HDPV>>'` fails with `ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLCLIDriver`

Comment: I think the above is also know issue. Basically we need an environment which does not have issues relating to Hive. Only other options left are `pyspark` shell and `SparkR` shell