# Ignoring non-spark config property: hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, spark-shell

How to run a Spark-shell with `hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict`?

I try (as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53581393/287948))

```
  export SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=2; spark-shell  --conf "hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict" --properties-file /opt/_myPath_/sparkShell.conf'
```

but Warning  "Ignoring non-spark config property: hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict"

---

PS: using Spark version 2.2.0.2.6.4.0-91,  Scala version 2.11.8

#### NOTE

The demand arrives after error on `df.write.mode("overwrite").insertInto("db.partitionedTable")`,

*org.apache.spark.SparkException: Dynamic partition strict mode requires at least one static partition column. To turn this off set  hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict*

Answer (score 12):

You can try using `spark.hadoop.*` prefix as suggested in [Custom Spark Configuration](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/configuration.html#custom-hadoophive-configuration) section for version 2.3. Might work as well in 2.2 if it was just a doc bug :)

```
spark-shell \
  --conf "spark.hadoop.hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true" \
  --conf "spark.hadoop.hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict" \
  ...
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and only found the workaround to set the config directly in the process before writing like

```scala
spark.conf.set("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
df.write(...)
```