# How can I enable hive dynamic partition in my local pyspark session

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to enable dynamic partition in my local spark session (not in application mode)

I'm running below commands in my pyspark shell (using spark 2.4)

spark.sqlContext.setConf("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
spark.sqlContext.setConf("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")

getting below error 
AttributeError: 'SparkSession' object has no attribute 'sqlContext'

Comment: seems to be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58633753/ignoring-non-spark-config-property-hive-exec-dynamic-partition-mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try to get context as

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(spark.sparkContext)
sqlContext.setConf("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true") 
sqlContext.setConf("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
```