# Set HIVE properties via PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, pyspark

I want to overwrite a partition in a given table. The SQL command is already prepared and works just fine when executed in HIVE directly:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE mytable PARTITION (dt, event_name) SELECT * FROM mytable2
```

in order to manage the file sizes, I set some HIVE properties in advance like this:

```
SET hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize=268435456;
SET mapreduce.map.memory.mb=20000;
SET hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions=50000;
SET mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=20000;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
SET mapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx18000m;
SET hive.merge.size.per.task=268435456;
SET mapred.max.split.size=70000000;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
SET mapreduce.reduce.java.opts=-Xmx18000m;
SET mapred.min.split.size=35000000;
```

this ensures that all files that are written are >256MB which is what I want.
Now I need to execute this script from PySpark as I am looping over different source tables and I use the following code to set the properties accordingly in my SparkContext and also HiveContext/SqlContext:

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("my script").setMaster(master)

config_settings = {
    'mapreduce.map.memory.mb': '20000',
    'mapreduce.map.java.opts': '-Xmx18000m',
    'mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb': '20000',
    'mapreduce.reduce.java.opts': '-Xmx18000m',
    'hive.exec.dynamic.partition': 'true',
    'hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode': 'nonstrict',
    'hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize': '268435456',
    'hive.merge.size.per.task': '268435456',
    'mapred.max.split.size': '70000000',
    'mapred.min.split.size': '35000000',
    'hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions': '50000',
    #'hive.exec.compress.output': 'true',
    #'parquet.compression': 'GZIP',
}

map(lambda x: conf.set(x[0], x[1]), config_settings.items())

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

map(lambda x: sqlContext.setConf(x[0], x[1]), config_settings.items())

sqlContext.sql("INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE mytable PARTITION (dt, event_name) SELECT * FROM mytable2")
```

however, this does not seem to work as it only generates files of the default size (64 MB)
I tried this with Spark 1.6 and also with 2.3 and different variations on how to set those properties but none seem to work.

when I call sc._conf.getAll() or sqlContext.getConf(...) it looks like all properties are set correctly.

what would be the right syntax to set these configurations so these are also obeyed when using sqlContext.sql("INSERT OVERWRITE ...") ?

Comment: Spark uses its own libraries for SQL parsing / data reading / data processing / data writing. Most of the properties you mention are specific to Hive and to MapReduce and hence ignored by Spark _(some would be ignored by TEZ, too)_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to control partition size in Spark SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38249624/how-to-control-partition-size-in-spark-sql)

Comment: thanks @mazaneicha for link I will give it a try and report back as soon as I have the results!

Comment: setting
sc.hadoopConfiguration.setInt("mapred.min.split.size", minSplit)
sc.hadoopConfiguration.setInt("mapred.max.split.size", maxSplit)
had some impact, but also not the desired/expected one. File sizes got bigger, but still not within the specified range

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32586793/howto-add-hive-properties-at-runtime-in-spark-shell